# C++ - Is there any command likes addr2line on Windows

Tags: c++, debugging, crash, addr2line

If a Windows application crashed on user's device without pdb, it would produce callstack like this:

```
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 1c0c9f1 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 4b8a97c 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 4b8a4f1 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 3608413 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 3630e94 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 413a33e 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 4151d46 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 149c9e6 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 149cc90 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 419cddd 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 41ab698 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 3a909df 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 3a999ff 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 38fd369 
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 338688  
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 34827c  
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 3482da  
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 355e16  
TestGame  0x000000003f790000 + 5169f2e 
kernel32      0x0000000076ec0000 + 159cd   
ntdll         0x0000000076fe0000 + 5383d
```

but I have .PDB file on development device, so I want address source line through .PDB. I know a command `addr2line` that can address line through .so file on Linux, I wonder if there's a command like `addr2line` on Windows.

Comment: You can load the dump file in visual studio or windbg, so long as the pdb matches then it should be able to resolve back to your code and line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open TestGame.exe in windbg, you need exactly same binary. Break execution. Load the .pdb for that version. Run the following command:

```
ln TestGame.exe+0x1c0c9f1
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to find this one: https://drmemory.org/page_symquery.html
If you don't get the module base address, try VS' dumpbin.exe /headers xxx.exe to get the image base.